# Check whether a string contains a specific word

Tags: python-2.7

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I looked around and couldn't find anything for my needs. I am a complete beginner to python, and I was wondering if there was a way to analyze a string to look for certain words using the built in modules. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for *Regular Expressions*.

Comment: don't wonder, read documentation, look for tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that returns `True` if it can find a word in a string, and `False` if it can't.

```
def isWordIn(word, string):
    return not(string.find(word) == -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a substring is in a string, you can issue

```
substring in mystring
```

Demo:

```
>>> 'raptor' in 'velociraptorjesus'
True
```

which interally calls the string's `__contains__` method. Depending on your definition of a word, you'd need a regular expression to check whether your word is surrounded by word-boundaries (i.e. \b).

```
>>> import re
>>> bool(re.search(r'\braptor\b', 'velociraptorjesus'))
False
>>> bool(re.search(r'\braptor\b', 'veloci raptor jesus'))
True
```

If your definition of a word is that it is surrounded by whitespace (or nothing), split your string:

```
>>> 'raptor' in 'velociraptorjesus'.split()
False
>>> 'raptor' in 'veloci raptor jesus'.split()
True
```

If your definition of a word is more complex, use a positive lookbehind and lookahead, i.e.:

```
bool(re.search(r'(?<=foo)theword(?=bar)', 'some string'))
```

where foo and bar can be anything you wish to find before and after the word.